# Error keeps throwing everytime i deploy my skill in ask-cli v2

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

[***enter image description here***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrk5S.png)

I recently migrated from ask-cli v1 to v2
Every time i create a skill to be AWS Lambda hosted. But when I deploy the skill using "ask-deploy" through command line, I keep getting this error again and again. I don't know where it goes wrong. The back-end code is PERFECT.
The front end is created in the developer console. However, the lambda function is not created.

This error keeps coming! Someone Please help me with this PLEASE

Comment: please find the screenshot of the error in the image description

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with code posted here - but it looks like one of the closing `'` somewhere in your files (JSON I guess) is incorrect.

Comment: Thank for answering. 
I get this same error across all my skills. 

"Even if" I create a skill with the basic "hello world template" and deploy it (without making any changes to the code and json", the same error throws up when I use "ask deploy"